# hook_form_alter not saving values to database

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, drupal-forms, hook-form-alter

I'm altering a form made through admin panel using below code to copy text from first textarea to second. This is done by clicking on 'Copy' button. Frontend works well as expected.

However when I submit the form using default submit button, values in textareas are not added to database. Therefore if I go to webform results from admin panel, I can't see any of the values.

Do I need to add anything to custom submit handler for this?

Thanks

```
function fence_quote_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'webform_client_form_1'){
    $form['input'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Input text'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="in-text">',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('Enter some text here... '),
        ),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $form['buttons']['fence_quote']  = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#value' => t('Copy'),
        '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'fence_quote_form_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'out-text',
        ),
    );


    $form['output'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Output text:'),
        '#prefix' => '<div id="out-text">',
        '#value' => '',
        '#attributes' => array(
            'placeholder' => t('Your text will appear here...'),
        ),
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );

    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_someform_custom_validation';

    $form['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit_function_submit';


  }

}


function fence_quote_form_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['output']['#value'] = $form_state['values']['input'];
  return $form['output']; 
}


function my_custom_submit_function_submit($form, &$form_state) {

}
```

Comment: Yes, you do need to make your submit function do something. The base form function only knows about the elements it defines. In most cases, if you add any custom fields, you'll have to handle those yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @reallyxloco Can you please guide me on how to add it to database? I'ma totally new to this stuff.

Comment: Assuming the form you're altering writes something to the database on submission, look at the base form submit function to see what's done. That should give you a good start. Also, check out the [Database API](https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/database) documentation.

Comment: The form I'm altering is a form I created from Webform frontend tools. Therefore no backend codes are created. It seems like this is going to be a complex task to save in to database, Can I at least know how to include these fields to the mail function so that I receive original fields values as well as custom field values in an email?

Comment: I guess I should have read your post more closely. If you created this form with the Webform UI, why aren't you just adding the fields there?

Comment: If you look closely, I need to add an extra button which cannot be done using UI.

Comment: Take a look at the webform_client_form_submit function. You'll get a feel of how they process data and save it to the database. They do use some helper functions, so it might be a little dense to crawl through. You should be able to see how they build a submission and how they use that when sending an email. It might be a little tricky using form elements not created with the webform UI though.